# Match Width of Parent in Column (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

By default, `Column {}` has the width of it's largest child element. How can I make all other elements to fit the width of the parent `Column`? If I use `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` the elements will take up the entire available space and make the parent `Column` larger. How can I achieve the same behavior like a `Modifier.matchParentWidth()` Modifier would provide?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The solution is to leverage the power of [intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements).

Instead of using `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` we use `width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to match the width to the minimum width of the largest element

Comment: Note: Trying this got me an error, so know that `IntrinsicSize` can't be used in LazyColumns and the like: Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc.

Answer (score 104):

You can use the Modifier **`.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)`**

```
 Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Gray)) {
            Text("Short text")
        }
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Yellow)) {
            Text("Extremely long text giving the width of its siblings")
        }
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Green)) {
            Text("Medium length text")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: any idea when to use  .Min vs .Max? the accepted answer uses .Min while yours is .Max.

Comment: @AngelKoh It doesn't make a difference if all children can only be rendered in a specific width.
Here however, when using `IntrinsicSize.Min`, the minimum width is chosen so the children can still be rendered "properly". Since `maxLines` of `Text` is not restricted by default it can happen that the text is wrapped into multiple lines when using `IntrinsicSize.Min` - so `IntrinsicSize.Min` can lead to a `Column` width smaller than `wrapContentWidth()` - That's what I observed. So `IntrinsicSize.Max` is preferrable here.

I could also imagine a difference if a child uses `Modifier.widthIn()`.

Answer (score 6):

Here I'm using `Modifier.fillMaxWidth` and the items doesn't make parent column larger : [image]

```
@Composable
fun Demo() {
Column(modifier = Modifier.width(300
    .dp)) {
    Text(text = "with fillMaxWidth modifier",modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Red))
    Text(text = "without fillMaxWidth modifier",modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Gray))
 }

}
```

What I usually do to achieve the `matchParentWidth` is something like this (It's dirty but gets the job done):

```
val context = AmbientContext.current.resources
val displayMetrics = context.displayMetrics
val scrWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density

Column(modifier = Modifier.width(300
    .dp)) {
    Text(text = "with fillMaxWidth modifier",modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Red))
    Text(text = "without fillMaxWidth modifier",modifier = Modifier
        .preferredWidth(scrWidth.dp)
        .background(Color.Gray))
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for dynamic sizing here. I can't specify a fixed size for the parent column. The column should be as wide as its widest child

Comment: This is the best solution if you want to have pixel perfect proportional geometry. Thanks. I was missing the  division by density! Big thanks.

Comment: Also what I achieved with it: https://gist.github.com/cicerohellmann/20f276f04a694e7bb588d84162169a73

Answer (score 5):

you can simply use `fillMaxWidth()`

```
 Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Cyan),) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp))
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.tom_jerry),
            contentDescription ="this is image",

            modifier = Modifier
                .size(40.dp)
                .clip(shape = CircleShape).align(CenterVertically),
            alignment = Alignment.Center,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight


        )
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Name : ${msg.name}")
            Text(text = "age : ${msg.age.toString()}")

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp)
    ) {
        // ...
        Button(
            { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
        ) {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.log_in))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is not only about matching `Text` Composables which return intrinsic sizes via Modifier's

```
@Stable
fun Modifier.width(intrinsicSize: IntrinsicSize) = when (intrinsicSize) {
    IntrinsicSize.Min -> this.then(MinIntrinsicWidthModifier)
    IntrinsicSize.Max -> this.then(MaxIntrinsicWidthModifier)
}
```

Then inside `MaxIntrinsicWidthModifier` with

```
override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.maxIntrinsicWidth(
    measurable: IntrinsicMeasurable,
    height: Int
) = measurable.minIntrinsicWidth(height)
```

> However, Intrinsic measurements don’t really measure the children
> twice. Instead, they do a different kind of calculation — you can
> think of it as a pre-measure step without requiring exponential
> measurement time, as it is cheaper and easier. So while this doesn’t
> exactly break the single measurement rule, it does bend it a little
> bit and shows a Compose requirement that falls outside of the usual
> ones.
>
> When creating a custom layout, Intrinsics provide a default
> implementation based on approximations. However, in some cases, the
> default calculation might not work for you as intended, so the API
> provides a way of overriding these defaults.
>
> To specify the Intrinsic measurements of your custom layout, you can
> override the minIntrinsicWidth, minIntrinsicHeight, maxIntrinsicWidth,
> and maxIntrinsicHeight of the MeasurePolicy interface during the
> measurement pass:

If you encounter such cases

https://medium.com/@lepicekmichal/compose-intrinsic-redraw-bug-2cdecef0f96c

[Row IntrinsicSize.Min not working when the children are async loading images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100247/row-intrinsicsize-min-not-working-when-the-children-are-async-loading-images)

[Android Jetpack Compose Row's height (IntrinsicSize.Min) is not stretched when children column generate more composables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67723017/android-jetpack-compose-rows-height-intrinsicsize-min-is-not-stretched-when-c)

Or If you use a parent with IntrinsicSize while any of content Composables are BoxWithConstratins, lazy lists, TabRow or etc. you get exception.

`Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc.`

In that case if you know which child will be bigger you can measure it inside a `Layout` first then measure rest using its width.

If any of these child composable can be widest you need to use SubcomposeLayout as in this question.

[Jetpack Compose set sibling Composables' width to longest one dynamically with SubcomposeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70361098/5457853)

Answer (score -2):

You are applying`Modifier.width(300.dp)` onto the parent column, the maximum width a child item in that column can occupy is `300.dp`.

Using `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` on your `Text` composable in this context is synonymous to using `Modifier.preferredWidth(300.dp)` because it can only get as wide as it's parent composable.

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for dynamic sizing here. I can't specify a fixed size for the parent column. The column should be as wide as its widest child