# Jetpack Compose: Row with all items same height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to implement a layout in Compose where the items of a horizontally scrollable `Row` should all have the same height, so smaller items should adjust to the size of the biggest item in the row. I know about [intrinsic size](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) but I just can't get it to work. Also I don't want to assign a fixed height to the `Row`, as the Row's height should also be the height of its biggest child composable.

This is the simplified layout

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .horizontalScroll(state = rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    ) {
        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " +
                    "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam"
        )

        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " +
                    "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam " +
                    "voluptua. At"
        )

        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Item(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.width(200.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Column {
            Text("Some static text")

            // Dynamic text
            Text(
                text,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp)
            )
        }

        // The space between these two composables should be flexible,
        // hence the outer column with Arrangement.SpaceBetween

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result

[image: what I get]

but what I actually want is

[image: what I want]

When I apply `fillMaxHeight()` to `Item`, the items take up the whole height and all buttons are aligned to the bottom of the screen.

Jetpack Compose version: 1.1.0

**Update:** This was a bug in Compose which was [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346000/416029) in `compose-foundation` version [1.3.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.3.0-beta01).

Comment: Adding `fillMaxHeight()` to `Item` should be enough in this case, and it works with two items, but doesn't work with 3 or more for some reason. It may be a bug, I suggest you [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) it.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov You're right, it works with two items and `fillMaxHeight()`?! When I reduce the width of items to for instance `100.dp`, it also works with three items. It seems that once an item completely leaves the viewport (because of the horizontal scroll), this breaks intrinsic measurement. Definitively feels like a bug. I will report it.

Comment: I tried removing scrollable and the issue is still there, so it's not related. But I thought too about view being fully out of container bounds

Comment: I reported the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218885161)

Comment: Is there a solution that supports LazyRow?

Comment: @dazza5000 Using `LazyRow` or `LazyColumn` with intrinsic size is currently (Compose 1.1.1) not possible. It will result in the following exception `Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc.`

Comment: I know - what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @dazza5000 I'm sorry but I don't have a solution. The problem which I described above is a bug in Compose which has not yet been fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still an issue with Compose 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behaviour is a bug in Compose which I [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218885161) on Feb 11, 2022. It was [marked as fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218885161#comment4) on Aug 13, 2022. However it is yet unknown which Compose version will contain this fix.

**Update:** The bug was fixed in `compose-foundation` version [1.3.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.3.0-beta01).

Answer (score 40):

This method is only applicable if you have a small list, as Row() loads all items at once (not lazily)

As of Compose v1.3.0 Lazy lists don't support `modifier.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)`

So for now we have to use Row with `modifier = modifier.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)`

When writing RowItem add `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))` to fill empty space

```
@Composable
fun RowItem(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Surface(
    modifier = modifier,
    color = Color.Gray,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        repeat((1..4).random()) {
            Text(
                text = "item $it",
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(
                    horizontal = 16.dp,
                    vertical = 4.dp
                )
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) // this is required to push below composables to bottom

        Button(onClick = {
        }) { Text(text = "Button") }
    }
}}
```

Make sure to add  `horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())` to make Row scrollable and `height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)` to make the height of all cards to the tallest item.

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableRow() {
Row(
    Modifier
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState()) // this makes it scrollable
        .height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max) // this make height of all cards to the tallest card.
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    content = {
        repeat(4) {
            RowItem(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight())
        }
    },
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
)}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was a bug in Compose which was fixed in [1.3.0-beta01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346000/416029). So my code is working now since Compose 1.3.0+ :)

Comment: Thx! It's helped with my problem. **height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)** for container.

Answer (score 6):

I created a solution that is not recommended by Google, but works well for us.

```
fun Modifier.minimumHeightModifier(state: MinimumHeightState, density: Density) = onSizeChanged { size ->
    val itemHeight = with(density) {
        val height = size.height
        height.toDp()
    }

    if (itemHeight > state.minHeight ?: 0.dp) {
        state.minHeight = itemHeight
    }
}.defaultMinSize(minHeight = state.minHeight ?: Dp.Unspecified)

class MinimumHeightState(minHeight: Dp? = null) {
    var minHeight by mutableStateOf(minHeight)
}
```

You then configure and apply the modifier to everything you want to have the same minimum height

```
val density = LocalDensity.current

val minimumHeightState = remember { MinimumHeightState() }
val minimumHeightStateModifier = Modifier.minimumHeightModifier(
    minimumHeightState,
    density
)
```

These were all in a LazyRow

```
    itemsIndexed(items = carouselModel.subviews, key = { _, item -> item.id }) { _, item ->
        when (item) {
            is BasicCard -> {
                FooCard(
                    modifier = minimumHeightStateModifier,
                    section = item,
                    onAction = onAction
                )
            }
            is BarCard -> {
                BarVerticalCard(
                    modifier = minimumHeightStateModifier,
                    section = item,
                    onAction = onAction
                )
            }
```

A discussion about the solution on the kotlin slack can be found here: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1649956718414129

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was a bug in Compose which was fixed in [1.3.0-beta01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346000/416029). So my code is working now since Compose 1.3.0+ :)

Answer (score 5):

The following example produces the behavior you're looking for. It utilizes intrinsic sizes.

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewTest() {
    Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Red)
                .size(size = 80.dp)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)
                .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 80.dp, minHeight = 40.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 80.dp, minHeight = 40.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read the comments to my post? I believe the mentioned behaviour is a bug in Compose.

Answer (score 3):

Implenting such a feature to set height of each element is possible with `SubComposeLayout` which lets you to remeasure your composables based on new metrics such as sibling with max width or height.

You can check description of SubComposeLayout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663194/jetpack-compose-how-does-subcomposelayout-work), or my answer to have Columns with equal widths [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361098/jetpack-compose-set-sibling-composables-width-to-longest-one-dynamically-with-s/70383797#70383797).

```
@Composable
fun SubcomposeRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
) {

    SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints ->

        var recompositionIndex = 0

        var placeables: List<Placeable> = subcompose(recompositionIndex++, content).map {
            it.measure(constraints)
        }

        placeables.forEachIndexed() { index: Int, placeable: Placeable ->
            println("Index: $index, placeable width: ${placeable.width}, height: ${placeable.height}")
        }

        var rowSize =
            placeables.fold(IntSize.Zero) { currentMax: IntSize, placeable: Placeable ->
                IntSize(
                    width = currentMax.width + placeable.width,
                    height = maxOf(currentMax.height, placeable.height)
                )
            }


        // Remeasure every element using height of longest item as minHeight of Constraint
        if (!placeables.isNullOrEmpty() && placeables.size > 1) {
            placeables = subcompose(recompositionIndex, content).map { measurable: Measurable ->
                measurable.measure(
                    Constraints(
                        minHeight = rowSize.height,
                        maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
                    )
                )
            }

            rowSize =
                placeables.fold(IntSize.Zero) { currentMax: IntSize, placeable: Placeable ->
                    IntSize(
                        width = currentMax.width + placeable.width,
                        height = maxOf(currentMax.height, placeable.height)
                    )
                }
        }

        layout(rowSize.width, rowSize.height) {
            var xPos = 0
            placeables.forEach { placeable: Placeable ->
                placeable.placeRelative(xPos, 0)
                xPos += placeable.width
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Constraints in second measurement is important since we want each composable to have max height

```
                Constraints(
                    minHeight = rowSize.height,
                    maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
                )
```

Usage

```
@Composable
fun Screen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    SubcomposeRow(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .horizontalScroll(state = rememberScrollState()),
    ) {
        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " +
                    "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam"
        )

        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " +
                    "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam " +
                    "voluptua. At"
        )

        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Item(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Red),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow)) {
            Text("Some static text")

            // Dynamic text
            Text(
                text,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp)
            )
        }

        // The space between these two composables should be flexible,
        // hence the outer column with Arrangement.SpaceBetween

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 20.dp),
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have not tried it out yet but this seems to be quite some code for the rather simple layout that I try to achieve. Do you agree, as assumed in the comments to my post, that this strange behaviour feels like a Compose bug?

Comment: @SvenJacobs you should only consider `SubcomposeRow` as new code, since rest is just to demonstrate how to use it. And compared to `Row` code or implementing this behavior with a custom `View` it's quite simple and straightforward. I agree with the bug part but with compose it's so easy to build your own Composable based on your needs easier and faster than you do with views. Added colors to demonstrate composable bounds.

Comment: Is there a variant that will work with LazyRow?

Comment: No because by definition LazyRow probably won't know the height of all the items because it doesn't create them until they are needed.

Comment: do you have this solution for pager?

Answer (score 2):

A little late but here is the solution. You were almost there. What you want is the height of the row to be equal to the Max height out of all the sub-column items, so what you want is to set the row height to "IntrinsicSize.Max". The trick is to use a Spacer() compose to fill in any space needed to be filled, without affecting the Intrinsic Height of the column itself. If you set the weight of the spacer to "1f" it will fill the remaining space.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Screen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            //**SET HEIGHT TO INSTRINSICSIZE.MAX**
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            .horizontalScroll(state = rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    ) {
        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " +
                    "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam"
        )

        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " +
                    "eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam " +
                    "voluptua. At"
        )

        Item(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Item(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.width(200.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Column {
            Text("Some static text")

            // Dynamic text
            Text(
                text,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp)
            )
        }
        //**THIS IS THE TRICK**
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        // The space between these two composables should be flexible,
        // hence the outer column with Arrangement.SpaceBetween

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

[see resulting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAd6b.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was a bug in Compose which was fixed in [1.3.0-beta01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346000/416029). So my code is working now since Compose 1.3.0+ :)

Answer (score 2):

For LazyRow, you can get the height of the row like this:

```
val rowHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { lazyRowtState.layoutInfo.viewportSize.height.toDp() }
```

Then simply set the height to the child.

Comment: If I do this, the height of the children will be set to 0.

Comment: Seems like the right solution for now. Use this height as heighIn(min = rowHeight). It'll lead to unnecessary recomposition though, but there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem I used `onTextLayout` in `Text()`.

```
onTextLayout = { result ->
 val offsetLines = result.multiParagraph.maxLines - 
                   result.multiParagraph.lineCount
 if (offsetLines > 0)
     text = text.plus("/n".repeat(offsetLines))
 }
```

find the minimum lines and add space until all my texts in carts have a same height.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who came across this question looking for a solution for `LazyLists`, I seem to have found one. This is for `LazyVerticalGrid`, but could probably be tweaked to work for any `LazyList`.

Essentially, using `visibleItemsInfo` we can find the max height of items in each row, and set that as the height for every item in that row.

```kotlin
val state = rememberLazyGridState()
val density = LocalDensity.current

LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 150.dp),
    state = state
) {
    itemsIndexed(myItemStates) { index, myItemState ->
        val row = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.find { it.index == index }?.row
        val itemsInRow = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.filter { it.row == row }
        val maxHeightInRow = itemsInRow.maxOfOrNull { it.size.height }
        val maxHeightInRowDp = with(density) { maxHeightInRow?.toDp() } ?: Dp.Unspecified
        MyItem(
            state = myItemState,
            modifier = Modifier.height(maxHeightInRowDp)
        )
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is doing too much work during composition, or breaking some kind of Compose rule, but it seems to work for me and I haven't had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I used kinda messy (by my standards) solution for `LazyRow`. It is a combination of dummy element in the `Row` and `Modifier.onPlaced` to calculate minHeight for all elements.

```
val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
val minHeight = remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val placedModifier = remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        Modifier.onPlaced {
            minHeight.value = with(localDensity) { 
                scrollState.layoutInfo.viewportSize.height.toDp() 
            }
        }
    )
}

// Removing placed modifier to prevent height recalculation every time Row moves.
LaunchedEffect(minHeight.value) {
    if (minHeight.value > 0.dp) {
        placedModifier.value = Modifier
    }
}

LazyRow(
    modifier = placedModifier.value,
    state = scrollState
) {
    // This is dummy longest card used to calculate height of other cards.
    if(minHeight.value <= 0.dp) {
        item {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier.width(0.dp),
                .... Longest possible content should be displayed in this card ....
            )
        }
    }

    // This contains actual cards with the data
    items(data) { content ->
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.heightIn(min = minHeight.value)
            .... Content ....
        )
    }
}
```

Hopefully it will help someone.