# Dynamic Item width in Column (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have some LazyColumn (or Column) in Composable fun:

```
@Composable
fun MyColumn(items: List<Item>) {
    val width = 0.dp // max for all amounts
    LazyColumn {
        items(items) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(text = it.title, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Text(text = it.amount, modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).width(width))
            }
        }
    }
}

class Item(val title: String, val amount: String)
```

How can I measure the ***width*** param? It must be equals the longest value for all amounts in ***items***.

Comment: You need to use SubcomposeLayout to get longest width and call subcompose and measue all of the composable to this width. You can check out answers below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70383797/5457853 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361098/jetpack-compose-set-sibling-composables-width-to-longest-one-dynamically-with-s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925896/how-can-i-make-the-two-buttons-the-same-width-when-i-use-jetpack-compose/72940620#72940620

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but when I launch my LazyColumn after width's measuring, it crashes with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints

Comment: How do you use it? LazyColumn cannot be measured with Constraints.Infinity as max height while LazyRow not with max width as Constraints.Infinity. And using a SubcomposeLayout instead of Row shouldn't throw exception

Comment: So. I thought better and realized that I didn't understand anything. Could you write specifically where exactly I should use SubComposeLayout - for each row in the column or for the entire column? I understand how SubComposeLayout can help in changing the size within a single row, but how do I take the longest width of the amount among ALL rows into the column. I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got some solution (I don't know is it correct or no, but it works):

1. I use *SubcomposeLayout* to measure ***width*** of whole separate column with amounts. Code of the measuring function:

   ```
    @Composable
    fun WithCalculateWidth(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
                           contentForCalculate: @Composable () -> Unit,
                           dependentContent: @Composable (Dp) -> Unit) {
        SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints ->
            val measuredWidth = subcompose("viewToMeasure", contentForCalculate)[0].measure(Constraints()).width.toDp()
            val contentPlaceable = subcompose("content") { dependentContent(measuredWidth) }[0].measure(constraints)
            layout(contentPlaceable.width, contentPlaceable.height) {
                contentPlaceable.place(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. I use calculated ***width*** in my List:

   ```
    @Composable
    fun ListWithMeasuredAmounts(items: List<Item>) {
        val allAmounts: @Composable () -> Unit = {
            Column {
                items.forEach {
                    AmountItem(amount = it.amount)
                }
            }
        }

        WithCalculateWidth(contentForCalculate = { allAmounts() }) { amountWidth ->
            LazyColumn {
                items(items) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        Text(text = it.title, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                        AmountItem(amount = it.amount, modifier = Modifier.width(amountWidth))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun AmountItem(amount: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        Text(text = amount, modifier = modifier.background(Color.Red))
    }
   ```

Comment: Your code crashes with 
IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints