# How to show semi-transparent loading overlay above full Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

I am trying to create a Composable that wraps another `content` Composable and displays a `CircularProgressBar` as an overlay on top of it, covering the whole `content` Composable.

I almost got it working as wished, see the following to images:

**Initial state**

[image: Initial state]

**Loading state**

[image: Loading state]

But as you can see, the overlay fills the complete screen instead of just the gray `LazyRow` item and the text field. Thus, the button is pushed off screen.

This is my current code:

```
@Composable
fun LoadingBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isLoading: Boolean = false,
    loadingText: String,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {

        content()
        if (isLoading) {

            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .alpha(0.5f),
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                    Text(text = loadingText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the screenshots, I am providing the gray box and the text field as the `content` parameter. So the overlay should only cover the gray `LazyRow` item and the text field.

I already stumbled across [instrinsic measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942711/match-width-of-parent-in-column-jetpack-compose), however I cannot use them as the App crashes when I provide a LazyRow as `content` due to following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc. To mitigate this:
- if intrinsic measurements are used to achieve 'match parent' sizing,, consider replacing the parent of the component with a custom layout which controls the order in which children are measured, making intrinsic measurement not needed
```

Comment: You are using `fillMaxSize()` in the `Surface`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should:

- add `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` in the parent `Box`
- Remove the `Surface`
- remove the `verticalArrangement` in the `Column`
- Add an other `Box` which you can fill with a translucent background

Something like:

```
Box(modifier = modifier
    .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {

    content()
    if (isLoading) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .background(Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.5f))

        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            androidx.compose.material.CircularProgressIndicator()
            Text(text = loadingText)
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is fairly close, but by doing this, the content behind the overlay remains 100% visible. If you look at my second image closely, the content behind the loading overlay should be a little "dimmed", that's why I used the `Surface` and applied the alpha there.

Comment: Thank you, `matchParentSize()` does the magic!