# Jetpack Compose with Resizable Background Image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

Currently, I'm a bit stuck on having a resizable drawable in the background of a card.

```
 Card(
        modifier,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        elevation = 6.dp
    ) {
        Image(
            painterResource(...),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Box() {
            Surface(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                contentColor = Color.White
            ) {

                Column(Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Text(...)
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Text(...)
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
                    Text(...)
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Button(...))
                    
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

What I really am trying to get is the image to resize accordingly to the contents of the card...but not doing that. Basically, it doesn't matter if the image is cropped, but I'm trying to make it **fill** the card. Right now, since I have FillWidth, on bigger screens like tablets, there is a large unused space at the bottom of the card.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Tried replacing the whole card with a box instead, didn't work, different permutations of contentscale also did not help.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721204/3585796) answer?

Comment: Yes... still trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: Mainly I can't make the image scale to the card parameters...and I really don't want to hardcode size numbers

Comment: as the answer says, you need `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)` on your card, after that `fillMaxWidth` should work as you expect