# Is there a way to make a composable as tall as other composables within a row?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, composable

```
Row {
   Foo()
   Bar(cellSize = 80) 
}
```

I have two composables `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar`'s size is dependent on `cellSize` and after the calculation `Bar` usually ends up taller than `Foo`.

`Foo` contains a box with certain content. I want `Foo` to be as tall as `Bar` but adding a `modifier.fillMaxHeight()` to `Foo` just fills up the entire screen as opposed to the row

Comment: Have you tried assigning Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max) to row and modifier.fillMaxHeight() to Foo?

Comment: You can try it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942711/match-width-of-parent-in-column-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)){
   Foo(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxHeight)
   Bar(cellSize = 80) 
}
```

This will basically make the `Row` take the **height** of the **biggest child** in terms of height and then we assign a `fillmaxheight` modifier to `Foo()` so that it takes all the height.

Comment: This works great and is super cool!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make the **Foo** composable as tall as the **Bar** composable within a **Row**, while maintaining the original structure of your layout. One way to achieve this is by using a **Box** composable to wrap both **Foo** and **Bar**, and then applying a modifier to the **Box** to align both composables vertically and ensure that **Foo** takes up as much height as **Bar**.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
Row {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .weight(1f) // This will make the Box (and Foo) take up equal space as Bar
    ) {
        Foo()
    }
    Bar(cellSize = 80)
}
```

the **Box** will take up as much height as **Bar** due to the **fillMaxHeight()** modifier. The **weight(1f)** modifier ensures that the **Box** and Foo will take up equal space as **Bar** within the **Row**.

This approach maintains the structure of your layout while achieving the desired height alignment between **Foo** and **Bar**.